# Might have accidentally deleted pip

Tags: python, import, cmd, pip, libraries

I tried to update my computer's version of Python from 3.8 to 3.11.2, but I'm not sure if it was something I removed from PATH or I tried to update from the CMD incorrectly.

Any time I try to run pip install or anything pip related, this message pops up

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Even worse, when I try to check if I have python from CMD, this message shows

```
No installed Python found!
```

I checked if I have the exe file in my PATH and I do, so at this point I have no clue what is going on. Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you do ANY web searching for this before asking here?  pip is not included with Python. 
 You have to add it.  https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3.12.0a4. using Windows 10

There are two ways.

- `python -m pip install <package>`    # this must must be older
- `py -m pip install <package>`   # this must be newest version.

The second option is better.